# AngularJs Login Page - Possible Security Dangers

Tags: angularjs, security, authentication

Are there any possible security holes in using AngularJs to perform an $http.post that contains username and password from a login page?

Comment: Not more than in any other post request.

Comment: That's what I figured, but thought I would check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, "the answer is 'yes,'" but don't necessarily blame Angular! Many other considerations apply: is the link to the server encrypted ("https")? Do any residual copies of the password-value remain in memory? And so on and on and on. There are no "intrinsic" security vulnerabilities arising from the mere fact that JavaScript was used to `POST` something to the host.